# Determining the automorphism of a vertex transitive/Cayley graph which will map a vertex to another given vertex under some conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group, cayley-graphs

A Cayley graph is a vertex-transitive graph, meaning that given any two vertices $v_1, v_2$ in the vertex set of the graph $X$ ($V(X)$), there exists an automorphism $\phi:V(X) \rightarrow V(X)$, such that $\phi(v_1)=v_2$.

For a Cayley graph say, $X=Cay((\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_q, \{s,t\})$, where $|s|=q,|t|=p$, let $\theta: \mathbb{Z}_q \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ be known.

As an example, when $q=3$, $\theta_s(t^iu^j)=s^{-1}t^iu^js=(t^{-j}u^{i-j})$, where ${t,u}$ forms a basis of $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ with $u= \theta_s(t)$.

For a vertex $v_1=(t^{k_1}u^{k_2},s^{k_3})$, if I trace along a sequence of edges, say $sts^{-1}t^2$, then it ends up at the vertex $v_2=(t^{m_1}u^{m_2},s^{m_3})$ (i.e. $v_1 sts^{-1}t^2 =v_2$).

Is it possible to find an automorphism $\phi:V(X) \rightarrow V(X)$, which will map $v_1$ to $v_2$ if I know the values of $k_1, k_2, k_3, m_1, m_2, m_3, t, s, \theta_s, p, q$ such that it will satisfy the following condition?

If I calculate the $\phi(v^\prime)$ for any other vertex $v^\prime \in X$, and get $\phi(v^\prime)=w$, then $w$ has to be a vertex present at a point obtained by tracing along the same sequence of edges (path) $sts^{-1}t^2$ starting at $v^\prime$. i.e. $v^\prime sts^{-1}t^2 =w$.

How to get such an automorphism if possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using the convention that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if $u^{-1}v$ is in the connection set. (In other words, connection set elements multiply "on the right".) Under this convention, the left regular representation is in the automorphism group. Your question is more or less asking which elements of the right regular representation are automorphisms. If $S$ is the connection set and $g$ is an element of the group, a little calculation shows that this happens if and only if $gSg^{-1}=S$.

Comment: I'll let you figure out what happens in your particular case (it might be that $g$ being the identity is the only possibility).

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @verret I will check it :)